# How Android Lollipop and other devices ask location permission?

Tags: android, permissions, manifest, location-services

After further research, i found that requestPermission only works on Android M. If i just include the permissions i needed in android manifest file, how does android ask user for the permission granted? For example, access fine location permission. I try including the requestPermission but never see the dialog.

Comment: Please provide your code.If you have grant,the dialog will not show.If your targetSdk is less than 23,the dialog will never show.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before Marshmallow, all the permissions are granted at installation time. That's why you don't see a dialog requesting permission on Lollipop and previous versions on runtime.

Check this out: [Runtime Permissions](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). It only applies to Marshmallow and above.